Running docker jenkins as https on a port other than 443
I recently encountered a problem because google chrome has enabled blocking downloads from sites that are not confirmed by a certificate and to which login is via HTTP. Of course it is possible to download the resulting file from jenkins but it is cumbersome.
My jenkins instance is launched from a docker container currently using such a command with port pointing: "docker run -d -v Jenkins_Production:/var/jenkins_home -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dorg.apache.commons.jelly.tags.fmt.timeZone=Europe/Warsaw -Duser.timezone=Europe/Warsaw"  --name Jenkins_Production -p 80:8080 -p 50001:50000 --restart always jenkins_configured_16_05:latest
"
The best way would be to redirect from host port 443 to the jenkins service only unfortunately there is already another service running on my server using port 443.
Here my question is if there is a possibility to use for example port 80 as https in jenkins and then upload a certificate to make the site fully secured ?
Thanks for your help

i dont think port number has anything to do with  it being secure or not , webmin runs on 10000 , and can be uploaded with ssl , its the capability of the application that needs to be enabled
